# QGIS WMS Server

Tags: qgis, wms, style, server

I have successfully installed QGIS Server on Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid.
The QGIS project file I want to publish as WMS was created with QGIS 2.6.1
The data is stored in shapefiles, the GetCapabilties request works.

Now I have the following issue:

if I add a line layer in QGIS Desktop or ArcMap, the colour of the line is not rendered correctly - it should be red but it is black.
The line style was made in QGIS, it is a marker line with a font marker and a simple red line using a custom dash pattern.

Even if I change the style to a simple green line - no dash pattern, no markers -  it is rendered black.

Polygon fills are rendered with the correct colour though, so it is not all monochrome.

any ideas?