# QGIS WMS Server line style

Tags: qgis, wms, style

I have the same problem reported here ([QGIS WMS Server](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138236/qgis-wms-server)), i have one project created in Qgis desktop (tried windows and ubuntu flavors), then exported WMS into Qgis server (ubuntu). All line layers are rendered black loosing their styles. Polygons are rendered ok.

Any ideas?